# OpenGL - tell vertex shader that VBO has changed

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently writing a program that requires updating my VBO data constantly.
However, I found out that if I call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)` after I initialize my buffer, the window closed itself somehow.
Below is my code snippet:

```
 glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pts[0]) * pts.size(), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

 vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
 glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_text, NULL);
 glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

 fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_text, NULL);
 glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

 program = glCreateProgram();
 glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
 glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
 glLinkProgram(program);

 mvp_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
 vpos_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPos");

 glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos_location);
 glVertexAttribPointer(vpos_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
      sizeof(float) * 3, (void*) 0);

 while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glUseProgram(program);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(pts[0]) * pts.size(), &pts);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    mat4x4_mul(mvp, m, p);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_location, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*) mvp);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, pts.size());
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

FYI: pts is constantly updated.

IS there a way to tell vertex shader that the VBO data is updated?

Edit: updated the code snippet

Edit: I am supposed to draw `pts.size()` number of vertices each time but there is only one point appeared on the screen

Comment: Why are you calling `glBindBuffer` before you draw it?

Comment: I just followed some tutorials which says that `glBindBuffer` would flush data in the buffer

Comment: Provide a link to this tutorial; I suspect that either you're misunderstanding what it said or the tutorial is stupid. Either way, you still need to provide a [mcve], and the above snippet is missing far too much stuff to know what's going on.

Comment: You don't need to tell the vertex shader. The vertex shader uses whatever is in the VBO on draw. This is whatever was uploaded with glBufferSubData

Answer (score 1):

Right before your draw call there where you have glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer); you need to actually set the attrib pointer(glVertexAttribPointer()). A secondary note is that GlVertexAttribPointer() binds GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to the specified attribute pointer. Where you call it at the moment there is nothing bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.

For reference GLEnum error = glGetError() will return an the error state of openGL and is a powerful debugging tool. If you're using glew, glewGetErrorString() will get a string for any non-zero error code which explains the error in more detail.

p.s. sorry for my poor writing skills.

Comment: Most of this is wrong. Vertex attribute state is completely independent from the active program, so where `glUseProgram()`is called has nothing to do with it. Also, a stride value of 12 looks correct, since that's the size in bytes of a vertex if it consists of 3 float values. The stride is the number of bytes between the **start** of one vertex and the start of the next. The only part of this answer that's really correct is that the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding needs to be valid when `glVertexAttribPointer()` is called.

Comment: Then that's the partt I'll leave

Comment: Ah my confusion is that of you set stride to zero Then the vertices are assumed to be tightly packed,but the zero just signifies that assumption

Comment: Do I need to call `glVertexAttibPointer()` again after I call `glBufferSubData()` ?

Comment: since currently there is only one point drawing on the screen